# How to apply other components to one path of Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.
With a single path, I want to check the mobile and apply different components.
(I'm using custom Router.js and installed 'nuxt-device-detect')

For example:

`javascript
import DesktopSomeComponent from '~/pages/desktop/some'
import MobileSomeComponent from '~/pages/moile/some'
export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: isMobile ? MobileSomeComponent : DesktopSomeComponent
      },
      ...
    ]
  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue-router [only allows one component per route](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/76#issuecomment-131392316). This is the main reason for your code to not work as intended.

A [possible solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/76#issuecomment-278175628) is to have a functional component to nest this logic:

```
export default {
  functional: true,
  render(h) {
    return isMobile 
    ? h('MobileSomeComponent')
    : h('DesktopSomeComponent')
  }
}
```